# How to Approach Segmentation Fault ( memory Leak ) Fortran function with C Interface?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fortran, gfortran, nvcc

I am calling a Netlib Fortran function of libport.a in C interface. I get segmentation fault at function `istkin_()` followed by segfault at `dgqex_()`. http://www.netlib.org/port/. This has both the functions mentioned above, https://github.com/AmbikaB29/Port3.

Following command used to compile and execute:

```
nvcc --compiler-options -fpie -g -use_fast_math --disable-warnings -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -c test_C4.c -lstdc++
gfortran -fcheck=all,no-array-temps -fstack-protector-all -Wall -ggdb3 -Wno-main -fno-second-underscore -use_fast_math  test_C4.o -L/usr/local/lib -lport  
./a.out
```

I tried checking using Valgrind in debug mode using the following command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --verbose --log-file=valgrind-out.txt ./a.out
```

I am posting a concise complete code to generate the error.

```
// -----------------
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct CSTAK;
struct { 
double DS[4000];
int  LS[8000];
int  IS[8000];
} CSTAK; 
extern void istkin_(const int ,const int );
extern void dgqex_(int NQUAD,double PQUAD[],double WQ[]);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    struct CSTAK;
// Quadrature Variables
        const int NQUAD=25;
        int i;
          double PQUAD[NQUAD], WQ[NQUAD]; //Port Variables
//        double *PQUAD=(double*)malloc(NQUAD*sizeof(int));
//        double *WQ=(double*)malloc(NQUAD*sizeof(int));
      
        istkin_(4000,4);// netlib port Initializes Stack 
        dgqex_(NQUAD,&PQUAD[1],&WQ[1]); // netlib port Guass Quadrature

    for (i=0; i< NQUAD;i++)
    {
    
    printf("P[%d]=%lf\n",i,PQUAD[i] );
    }
//        realloc(PQUAD, 0);
//        realloc(WQ,0);                
    free(PQUAD);
    free(WQ);


}
```

I get the segfault error with memory leak with both statically defined array or dynamically allocated memory for `PQUAD` and `WQ` variable.

Valgrind log-file :

Heap Summary:

```
==18301== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18301==     in use at exit: 5,444 bytes in 17 blocks
==18301==   total heap usage: 21 allocs, 4 frees, 13,584 bytes allocated
```

Note additional information: I checked the two function with f95/gfortran compiled and executed. It gave no error on compilation and run.

I am not sure if it is a good idea to even call Fortran legacy functions from C routine specially with CUDA. I rebuilt the libport library, all in vain. Is it do with the array indexing while passing variable by reference as for fortran &PQUAD(1) and for C &PQUAD[0]?

Comment: At a guess your Fortran functions need to be ___stdcall___

Comment: Also you shouldn't be freeing statically declared arrays.

Comment: There is a typo while copying the code to stack. Yes, I did commented it when I tried. Thank you for the catch regardless. @cup

Comment: Agree with Vladimir that you should really have edited the old question and have it reopened. But note we still do not have the prototype/interface to dgqex, it is not listed on the page you link to, and anyway it is better to provide all the information in the question. One likely cause of problems is you are not passing pointers for the integer arguments. But with what is shown I can't be sure - and I have no idea what you mean by "of libport.a in C interface". As far as I can tell you are just calling Fortran. If so use the standard methods for C to call Fortran.

Comment: @IanBush: Now I hope you can see why I posted the first question not focusing on reproducing the error even though that is the best practice. It is because these functions are probably way older than older processors we currently use. I feared there is no way to share this archive library in forum or privately to anyone on this platform, at least what I know so far, please let me know how one can do that, therefore my questions' error(s) are not reproducible as yet. Furthermore, an approach to resolve it might help. Well, thank you for your insight so far.

Comment: @IanBush I have tried passing the pointer for integer arguments before I posted the first questions with no luck. What I mean by saying "libport.a in C interface" is that I am linking fortran libport.a with test_C4.o an object file compiled with nvcc which is essentially  what you mentioned "you are just calling Fortran". I did use the standard method which worked for functions from other libraries.

Comment: @VladimirF This has both the functions mentioned above. https://github.com/AmbikaB29/Port3.git. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After much wait posting the working version of the above segmentation/memory leak issue:

````
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct CSTAK;
struct { 
double DS[4000];
int  LS[8000];
int  IS[8000];
} CSTAK; 
extern void istkin_(const int *,const int *);
extern void dgqex_(const int *,double *,double *);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    struct CSTAK;
// Quadrature Variables
        const int NQUAD=25;
        const int nSize=4000;
        const int nByte=4;
        int i;
          double PQUAD[NQUAD], WQ[NQUAD]; //Port Variables

        istkin_(&nSize,&nByte);// netlib port Initializes Stack 
        dgqex_(&NQUAD,&PQUAD[0],&WQ[0]); // netlib port Guass Quadrature

    for (i=0; i< NQUAD;i++)
    {
    
    printf("P[%d]=%lf\n",i,PQUAD[i] );
    }

} ```
````